# Как применяется ivar в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Я проходил тест по Objective C на it.mail.ru и хочу больше информации.

Вопрос: "Что будет заретейнино? (_instanceVariable это объект, ivar текущего объекта)

```
^{ NSLog(@"%@ ", _instanceVariable); }
```

Варианты ответов:

- Ничего
- self
- _instanceVariable
- и то, и то

Я ответил: "ничего", и это было отмечено как неверный ответ.
Ошибку я в своей логике вижу, _instanceVariable будет захвачен блоком.
Но будет ли заретейнен self?

Так же буду признателен за внятное описание, в каких случаях применяется ivar.
Все что я нашел в документации это:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/ivar?language=objc
- http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/9objc_runtime_reference/chapter_5_section_56.html

Понятнее мне не стало.

Answer (score 1):

`_instanceVariable` для компилятора аналогично `self->_instanceVariable`, таким образом, будет заретейнен ещё и self.

Instance variable напрямую использовать не рекомендуется, это описано в документе "Adopting Modern Objective-С" на сайте Apple Developer. Вместо этого предлагается использовать property с нужными атрибутами, для которых компилятор сам создаст соответствующие ivar'ы и сгенерирует геттеры и сеттеры.

Мне известны лишь следующие случаи, когда следует обращаться напрямую к ivar'ам вместо property:

1. В инициализаторах, поскольку геттеры и сеттеры могут иметь побочные эффекты, зависящие от ещё непроинициализированных свойств
2. В реализации протокола NSCopying при прямом переносе значений ivar'ов между исходным объектом и его копией (причина такая же, что и прошлом пункте)
3. В реализации собственных геттеров и сеттеров. Думаю, очевидно, почему.

Answer (score 0):

Будет заретейнен только `self`. Дмитрий пишет "еще и", подразумевая что будет заретейнено "и то, и то", но это не правильный вывод из правильного посыла о том, что для компилятора это переменная через стрелочку: `self->_instanceVariable`.